# Zoomed in when Mirrored

Tags: release-hera, display

I am using elementary OS 5.1.4 Hera, when I connect my my laptop to an external screen and turn `Mirror Display` (**ON**) my laptop screen is so zoomed that I cant see most of the screen no matter what. As you can see in the pic I don't have that much of a space to work with but I can still use the terminal. 
[image]

Answer (score 0):

I noticed that there is a glitch that sometimes happens when setting up mirror displays. The pixel doubling option gets enabled when it shouldn't.

**I cannot guarantee the following solutions work! If you get stuck you might need to look up some way to configure display options in the Terminal or TTY.** Maybe someone can add instructions as another solution or comment to this question.

After applying the display settings and clicking "Keep This Configuration" do one of the following:

- Use the tab, arrow and enter keys to get to the pixel doubling setting and disable it "blindly".

  - This is what I did. If you're unfamiliar with this, practice it before applying new display settings.
- You might be able to move the window by holding down the Command (also known as Super or Windows) key and the left mouse button to get the pixel doubling option on the screen this way.

  - This key and mouse button combination allows you to grab and move a window from any spot, not just the title bar.